# don't install illuminate/redis v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста, при любом исполнении команды composer дает ошибку

```
 Problem 1
    - don't install illuminate/redis v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/redis v7.20.0|remove laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - don't install illuminate/redis v7.20.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Installation request for illuminate/redis ^7.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/redis[v7.20.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.38, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38].
```

Буду рад кто подскажет в чем проблема и как решить.
вот файл composer

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "botman/botman": "^2.3",
    "botman/driver-botframework": "^1.1",
    "botman/driver-telegram": "^1.4",
    "botman/driver-web": "^1.4",
    "botman/studio-addons": "~1.5.0",
    "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "5.8.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "illuminate/redis": "^7.20",
    "imper86/allegroapi": "^3.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelrus/sleepingowl": "5.8.*",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.19",
    "symfony/cache": "^4.0",
    "thecodingmachine/discovery": "^1.2",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0",
    "vt-parhomenko/olx-ua-api-sdk": "dev-dev",
    "zizaco/entrust": "^1.9",
    "zoondo/allegro-api": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"

    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable" : true,
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь установить `illuminate/redis v7.20` но для его установки нужно:

Requires

- php: ^7.2.5
- illuminate/contracts: ^7.0
- illuminate/support: ^7.0

инфа тут: https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/redis

а у вас `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*"` и `"php": ">=7.1.3"`

либо установите `illuminate/redis ^v5.8` либо обновитесь до `php7.3 + laravel 7`